# MySQL cannot convert its engine from MyISAM to ARCHIVE

Tags: mysql, archive, myisam

The table whose engine needs to be converted is only for read purpose and its content will never change. So I want to convert the engine of the table as ARCHIVE, but when I tried to convert it, I got the error below.

```
Error Code: 1069. Too many keys specified; max 1 keys allowed
```

The version of MySQL is 5.5.
Is this index related problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can make some guesses at to what the two letter abbreviation in your image could mean: 'PK' is probably 'Primary Key' and 'AI' might mean 'Auto Increment', but I don't know what 'NN' stands for. Please explain.

Comment: [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73022) answer on the dba stackexchange might be able to help you

Comment: @KIKOSoftware NN stands for No NULL

Comment: @Shogunivar: Ah, yes, of course. So it is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it definitely is a `PK` problem since `archive` does **not** support `primary keys`. You can simply drop the primary key and it should work.

Refer to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73022) for examples on how to convert your db

Comment: I have dropped primary key. However, it still does not let me change the engine.

Comment: Have you tried the second approach of the link? You can make a copy of your database, change the engine of the new one, then insert all the data into the new one. Then drop the old one and change the name of the new one

Comment: @Shogunivar means "copy of your _table_", not "copy of your _database_".